# Carousel Slider with YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, slider, carousel

Is it possible to use JQuery to build a youtube video slider? I'd like to display a few ones I uploaded.

Found some answers but made with specific frameworks, if it's possible I'd like to stick with something simple.

I found this code very helpful but I can't seem to make it work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mb4vgn60/)

```
$('.play-button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.slider-video')[0].play();
});

$('.slider-video').on('play', function () {
    $(this).attr('controls', '1');
});

// Additionnal code for the slider
var pos = 0,
    slides = $('.slide'),
    numOfSlides = slides.length;

function nextSlide(){
    stopCurrentVideo();
    slides.eq(pos).animate({left:'-100%'},500);
    pos = pos >= numOfSlides-1 ? 0 : ++pos;
    slides.eq(pos).css({left:'100%'}).animate({left:0},500);
}

function previousSlide(){
    stopCurrentVideo();
    slides.eq(pos).animate({left:'100%'},500);
    pos = pos == 0 ? numOfSlides-1 : --pos;
    slides.eq(pos).css({left:'-100%'}).animate({left:0},500);
}

function stopCurrentVideo(){
    $('.slider-video:eq('+pos+')').load().removeAttr('controls')
    .siblings('.overlay-content').show().find('.play-button').show();
}

$('.left').click(previousSlide);
$('.right').click(nextSlide);
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can't make it work? What did you try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with the YouTube iFrame API:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

This API becomes available when you append `enablejsapi=1` to the URLs of YouTube video embeds.

In order to access the controls for stopping videos, for each video you need to access an instance of `YT.Player`. For each iFrame, I created an instance of `YT.Player`, and attached it directly to the `slide` object as a parameter called `video`.

(Note that many developers say you shouldn't attach data directly to DOM objects, but I did so here because it allowed me to more closely match your original code.)

`YT.Player` can be accessed through a special function that must be called `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, which I could only get to work if it was *outside* of `$(document).ready`.

I can't put my solution on JSFiddle because the iFrames don't play nice, so here's my implementation on GitHub:

http://robertakarobin.github.io/jquery-video-slider
https://github.com/robertakarobin/jquery-video-slider

Here are the relevant bits:

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="video-slider">
    <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
    <div class="slide">
        <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4?ecver=2&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <!-- SLIDE 2 -->
    <div class="slide">
        <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4?ecver=2&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF SLIDES -->
    <div class="slide-arrow left"></div>
    <div class="slide-arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pos = 0,
        slides = $('.slide'),
        numOfSlides = slides.length;

    function nextSlide() {
        // `[]` returns a vanilla DOM object from a jQuery object/collection
        slides[pos].video.stopVideo()
        slides.eq(pos).animate({ left: '-100%' }, 500);
        pos = (pos >= numOfSlides - 1 ? 0 : ++pos);
        slides.eq(pos).css({ left: '100%' }).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
    }

    function previousSlide() {
        slides[pos].video.stopVideo()
        slides.eq(pos).animate({ left: '100%' }, 500);
        pos = (pos == 0 ? numOfSlides - 1 : --pos);
        slides.eq(pos).css({ left: '-100%' }).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
    }

    $('.left').click(previousSlide);
    $('.right').click(nextSlide);
})

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    $('.slide').each(function (index, slide) {
        // Get the `.video` element inside each `.slide`
        var iframe = $(slide).find('.video')[0]
        // Create a new YT.Player from the iFrame, and store it on the `.slide` DOM object
        slide.video = new YT.Player(iframe)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The slider seems to be working fine. Just change the code from Video tag to YouTube Embed Code and you have a Youtube player Carousel.

```
<div class="video-slider">
<!-- SLIDE 1 -->
<div class="slide">
    <div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.28%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4?ecver=2" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
<!-- SLIDE 2 -->
<div class="slide">
    <div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.28%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EngW7tLk6R8?ecver=2" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
<!-- END OF SLIDES -->
<div class="slide-arrow left"></div>
<div class="slide-arrow right"></div>
</div>
```

You can get the YouTube Embed Code by right clicking on the video on youtube.com and select Copy Embed Code, and use that code in the slider.

Hope it helps.

I have made a fork of the author fiddle and made the changes. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ac3wnbup/1/)

Comment: This does not work. The HTML is missing a closing tag, and is not compatible with the code the author has written. It errors and fails on click.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin can you check the fiddle I have created, it seems to work.

Comment: The sliding works, but the videos do not stop/pause when sliding.